# Pillow keeps throwing cannot identify image file on Window in Python2.7.6

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I'm using Python2.7.6 and Pillow 2.3.0 on 32 bits Windows. And I do **not** have PIL installed on my machine.

My problem is when I do following I get *"cannot identify image file"* error.

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> file = open(r"C:\\a.jpg", 'r')
>>> image = Image.open(file)
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pillow-2.3.0-py2.7-win32.egg\PIL\Image.py", line 2025, in open
  IOError: cannot identify image file
```

But this works if I don't *"Open"* the file before opening it with `Image.Open`:

```
>>> image2 = Image.open(r"C:\\a.jpg", 'r')
```

NOTE: I cannot omit the *"Open"* statement.

Does anyone know what may be causing this strange behavior?

Thanks, in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do `image = Image.open(file)` , you already opened the file.

Try `image = Image.open("C:\\a.jpg")`

Here is the Image module: http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm

**EDIT:**

**Use 'rb' instea of 'r'** when opening the file

Comment: Thank you for your response! But unfortunately I have to open the image file first as a file before opening it as an image file. This "File" is being used in multiple places and it works fine on other platforms. I think this is strictly related to Windows issue.